# Firebase 2, accesing child values in snapshot produces nulls

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been attempting to utilize firebase's snapshots, but when I try to access specific children, the output is a null.

```
var ref = FIRDatabaseReference.init()

func loadData {
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(

    ref.child("Posts").child(postId).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        print(snapshot.value?["PostText"] as! String) // Optional(<null>)
        print(snapshot)
        for child in snapshot.children {

            if child.childSnapshotForPath("PostText").value == nil {
                self.postText.text = ""

            } else {
                self.postText.text = child.childSnapshotForPath("PostText").value as? String // Optional(<null>)

                print(child.childSnapshotForPath("PostText").value)
            }

        }
    })
}
```

Output of print(snapshot)

```
Snap (84844) {
Author = lGAV1KUhSCP8hnFiKY1N9lBPrmmst1;
CommentsCount = 1;
Group = 665555;
ImageUrl = "http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/03589/Wellcome_Image_Awa_3589699k.jpg";
PostText = "I like cakeh, but theijijijijijij truth is, it's too sweet. So SOMETIMES I dont eat it, but i LIKE CAKE.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your snapshot is a Dictionary. Then you have to cast it as a Dictionary:

```
    func loadData {
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(

        ref.child("Posts").child(postId).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

            print(snapshot.value?["PostText"] as! String) // Optional(<null>)
            print(snapshot)
            let dict = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
            if let author = dict["Author"] as? String, commentsCount = dict["CommentsCount"] as? Int, group = dict["Group"] as? Int {
                print("author \(author) commentsCount \(commentsCount), group: \(group)")
            }
        })
}
```

Do the same for ImageUrl and PostText, they should be cast as `String`